# event overlapping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".pswp__button pswp__button--close", function(event){
  //event.preventDefault();
  alert('f');
});
```

The class binds to other events in other scripts, so it's not firing. I tried `preventDefault()` but that doesn't work. I also tried to use `off()` like this

```
$(document).off("click", ".pswp__button pswp__button--close")
  .on("click", ".pswp__button pswp__button--close", function () {
     alert('fire');
  });
```

But no luck...I'm very sure it's overlapping, I tried other classes, there it was ok.

Comment: You're using a delegated event handler that won't process until the click event bubbles up to the `document`. If there are other handlers bound directly to the element or to parents between the element and the `document` and those handlers call `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` then your delegated handler won't be called. As an aside, what's with your class names?

Comment: That *should* work. It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/me0ubow7/).

Comment: @JoshCrozier - But not [here](http://jsfiddle.net/me0ubow7/1/)...

Comment: @JoshCrozier of course it worked that way, there is no overlap there

Comment: @JoshCrozier look at this, http://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/zxNEjV try to click close button